# iCloud file, 2 version saved 1 with extension 1 without

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, file, icloud

I'm one of the few developers out there who is actually using iCloud for data persistence amongst devices using the same app.  At the forefront, lol.  For the most part everything is working, with some minor hiccups here and there.  I am saving plist files using NSFileManager and UIDocument.

I have defined constants for the file names, yet some save with extensions and others don't?  When defined they include the .plist extension. There are 3 files, one never displays .plist, one does, and the third has both.

One of my files is saved twice 1 with extension, 1 without.  Same size so I have to assume they are identical.

Has anybody else encountered this issue?  Any solutions, what is the best practice for file naming?  By the way I can delete the files in iCloud and they reappear.  I have also implemented iCloud conflict resolution.

thank you